# How to expand/collapse multiple panels in angular?

Tags: angular, angular5

How to expand more than one Accordion(Panel) item at a time. Expand/collapse action can also be toggled by clicking on it again.

**categories.html**

```
<ul class="treeChildren"  *ngFor="let department of getAllDepartments; let i=index">
    <li class="treeChildrenItems">
        <div class="moduleListData" >
            <i (click)="showCategory(i);" [ngClass]="{'fa-caret-down': 'i == categoryIndex', 'fa-caret-right': 'i != categoryIndex'}" class="fa" ></i>
            <strong class="categoryName">{{department.departmentName}}</strong>
        </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**categories.compenent.ts**

```
// Currently its working for single panel Expand/Collapse
categoryIndex : Number ;
  showCategory(index){
    if (this.categoryIndex == index) {
      this.categoryIndex = NaN;
    } else {
      this.categoryIndex = index
    }
  }
```

Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/umF73.png

Comment: If you can adopt some design system, I recommend taking a look at https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples

Comment: are u using material angular ?

Comment: No, I am using Flexbox & no UI frameworks

Comment: I think you should look thru docs of Flexbox and UI frameworks that you use, because it expansion panel is not a thing of angular

Answer (score -1):

```
<ul class="treeChildren"  *ngFor="let department of getAllDepartments; let i=index">
    <li class="treeChildrenItems">
        <div class="moduleListData" >
            <i (click)="department.expanded != department.expanded" [ngClass]="{'fa-caret-down': department.expanded, 'fa-caret-right': !department.expanded }" class="fa" ></i>
            <strong class="categoryName">{{department.departmentName}}</strong>
        </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```